# Why some package-private classes are not obfuscated by Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

Working with an Android project in Android Studio 3.2, having enabled Proguard and some specific rules, I'm not able to figure out the following:

a specific package (and its subpackages) in a library module, used by client code, is preserved through the rule:

```
-keep public class com.mylib.mypackage.** {
    public protected *;
}
```

Now, within this package there are also a number of package-private classes, which should not be picked by that rule. Some of those classes are effectively obfuscated, both in their own names and their member names, which is fine.

Instead there are some classes, implementing public interfaces, whose class names are not obfuscated, while I'd expect they should. For completeness, their member names, when not part of interface, are effectively obfuscated.

Example:

```java
/* package */ class InternalComponent implements ExternalInterface {

  // ExternalInterface is kept: Ok
  // InternalComponent is kept: don't like, I'd like it renamed

  @Override
  public void ExternalMethod() {
    // this is kept: Ok
  }

  public void InternalMethod() {
    // this is renamed: Ok
  }
}
```

I'd like to highlight that `InternalComponent` is created within some other (kept) class and only returned to client code through the `ExternalInterface`.

How can I also obfuscate their class names as well, if possible?

**Edit #1**
After @emandt answer on Proguard output files, I double checked and `com.mylib.mypackage.InternalComponent` is listed in `seeds.txt`, which according to [this blog post](https://jebware.com/blog/?p=484) lists all items matched by keep rules. So, for some reason, the rule above also picks package-private classes, which still seems wrong to me.

**Edit #2**
In the meantime, I ended up doing exactly the same approach proposed by @shizhen. For completeness, in order to extend the exclusion to *any* package named `internal`, I modified my proguard rule as:

```
-keep public class !com.mylib.mypackage.**.internal.*, com.mylib.mypackage.** { 
    public protected *;
}
```

(note the first part before the comma, prefixed by `!`)

I'll mark @shizhen answer, though I'd like to be curious as to why the original rule is also picking package-private components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working on an **Android Library** project? Probably YES.

In order to achieve your purpose, I am afraid that you need to re-organise your packages into something like below:

**Public interfaces**

```
com.my.package.apiforusers
```

**Private/Internal implementations**

```
com.my.package.apiforusers.internal
```

Then for your obfuscation rules, you can have it like below:

```
-keep public class com.my.package.apiforusers.** { public *; }
```

So that **only** the public classes/interfaces are kept and all those ones inside `com.my.package.apiforusers.internal` will be obfuscated.

Please note the double-asterisk at the end so that public classes/interface are also kept for the sub-packages.

Answer (score 0):

In "/build/outputs/mapping/release/" folder there are few files ("usage.txt", "seeds.txt", etc..) that contain the REASONS of why and which classes/variables/methods/etc.. are not-processed/not-shrinked/ot-obfuscated via ProGuard utilities.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I had a look at those already, but could not figure out how to make a sense of them. `mapping.txt` is not useful in this scenario. Do you know how to make use of the other two?