# How to Obfuscated Jar or AAR files

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, obfuscation, aar

Can someone help me about, obfuscated  or give me example to do this?

I created an `.aar` file and `.jar` file and put the class of getter and setter that will give value if they access on it.

but the thing in need to put the hidden values that someone will not see what is the value on it.

```
     package com.example.test;
     public class MyClass  extends  privateClass{
            String testing;
            public MyClass() {
              this.testing = getStringExample();
            }
            public String getTesting() {
                return testing;
            }
            public void setTesting(String testing) {
                this.testing = testing;
            }
     }
```

and this class must be hide/obfuscated to the other developers  if i give my library

```
    package com.example.test;

    public class privateClass {
        String getStringExample()
        {
             return "TEST RESULT";
        }
    }
```

Note: I tried to put proguard too, and check the library but still they can see my private class, , i tried to use interface and extends the class but still the same,

here is my proguard example:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontwarn ccom.example.test.R*
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class
-keepclassmembers class com.example.test.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.eyefixdata.** {
    void set*(***);
    void set*(int, ***);
    boolean is*();
    boolean is*(int);
    *** get*();
    *** get*(int);
}
```

Please save my day. hope you help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the answer at [Why some package-private classes are not obfuscated by Proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52771418/8034839)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your private classes/interfaces to other packages, e.g. put your `privateClass` to an **internal** package `package com.example.your.library.internal;` to distinguish with your public classes/interfaces.

```java
package com.example.your.library.internal;

public class privateClass {
    String getStringExample()
    {
        return "TEST RESULT";
    }
}
```

And add below line to your proguard configuration

```
-keep public class com.example.your.library.* { public *; }
```

Note that you should use **single** wild char `*` to **NOT** obfuscate the internal packages.

Comment: Hello, @shizhen, can you teach me how can i put the privateClass to an internal package ?. step by step? thank you for helping me

Comment: "put into internal package" means nothing special but rename your package name to something like `com.example.your.library.internal`, this way of package name management is to facilitate your subsequent obfuscation rules.

Comment: Also check my another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52771418/8034839 for cross understanding.